# Multiple Computers Adding Data to One Document

Tags: vba, excel, multi-user

I have created an inventory tracking software that has a client side document that changes data in a master list that is located on a server using VBA macros.

This individual program will prompt the user for information and will then open the master list document and add the data to the next unfilled row.

I am currently having a problem because the client side program will be used on multiple computers at the same time all changing the master document at once. Is there any way to allow multiple users to manipulate the master document at the same time and work around excel's multi-user limitations?

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Name = InputBox("Enter your name")
    Workbooks.Open ("Master List.xlsm") 'Needs the file location path'
    Last_Row = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & Last_Row) = Name
    Workbooks("Master List.xlsm").Save
    Workbooks("Master List.xlsm").Close
End Sub
```

This is a very simplified version of the client side code.

Comment: You would be better off using a database for this.

Comment: Excel is not really intended for use by multiple users. If you cannot go with a database then look into `ADO` in Excel  - inserting and updating records with SQL. They are very short, so they can emulate database behavior on Excel if the count of users or the amount of writes/updates is small.

Comment: Is there a specific database software you would suggest? The macro also auto populates a form that needs to be printed out each time a new item is added to the master sheet.

Comment: Well you have Microsoft Office, so that usually means you have Microsoft Access already.

Comment: Can multiple users add items to an Access database at the same time?

Comment: Yup integrate this to Access, a DB has controls for multi user access and potential "collision".  You don't want to be writing request "threading" in VBA based on request time and a buffer.

Comment: try to insert "Workbooks.Open" in a "do until" loop (Don't forget to add a max limit of trials). if the workbook is used by another user then it will not take more than 1 second. so add "Application.Wait 1 second" between the trials. This should work